# How to recover my ubuntu .

Tags: 13.10

In ubuntu 13.10 I used the following command in my terminal, to gain root access:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "greeter-show-manual-login=true">> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf'
```

Than I restarted the system, but it seems my system has crashed. It's not even starting again. Is there any solution to fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

It probably boots but not into X.

Try to press Alt+2 when you think it might boot (or when it stops booting process) and log in. When you are in, use something like `sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and repair that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Login into virtual console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and then rename  `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file like below,

```
sudo mv /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.bak
```

Then restart your pc or restart your lightdm.

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```